# Build Docker Image sometimes takes too long in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-image, docker-build

I have .Net core project and need to create a Docker Image in VS 2019.
I have added Docker Support and file looks as below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestProject/TestProject.csproj", "TestProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestProject/TestProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestProject"
RUN dotnet build "TestProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestProject.dll"]
```

and invoked 'Build Docker Image'command. In output it keeps going as below for long time. The Docker Engine version I am using is v20.10.5

```
1>TestProject -> C:\Users\innabal1\Source\Repos\Test\Module\TestProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TestProject.dll
1>Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
1>docker build -f "c:\users\innabal1\source\repos\Test\Module\TestProject\dockerfile" -t abbabilityuatiotedgetest  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=TestProject" "c:\users\innabal1\source\repos\Test\Module"
1>#1 [internal] load build definition from dockerfile
1>
1>#1 transferring dockerfile: 32B done
1>#1 sha256:c2d7cee51b8990c4661bdea4a513d83b2b63195a923f06cd7232b3013b7af2ef
1>#2 sha256:375091a63344888a744e9839e646ca6a12186feeba552cf36b310f2d128d0d41
1>#2 transferring context: 35B done
1>#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
1>#2 DONE 0.0s
1>#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster
1>#3 sha256:e538d4b6638b129e5ce2a81d67897d05d7066a680a6604c538e8e2ca3206ce10
1>#1 DONE 0.0s
1>
1>#3 ...
1>#4 DONE 1.0s
1>
1>#4 sha256:bdcba2f81f21195ea1a342a722e7e589e34f2887f76120b9fd54c08595be97e1
1>#4 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim
1>
1>#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster
1>#3 sha256:e538d4b6638b129e5ce2a81d67897d05d7066a680a6604c538e8e2ca3206ce10
1>#3 DONE 3.7s
1>
1>#5 [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim@sha256:152c931d0633156e5a1365a5baf1caeba8a75a02e2d0a896553e9dc243bd09ac
1>#6 [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app
1>#5 DONE 0.0s
1>#6 sha256:4d893a1fb89eed5e27631f49871b5be0536eaa7b0f3fce6b76b3732d7cfa72f9
1>
1>#7 [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app
1>#7 sha256:ccc02f4d6a4f0b1c9e8a9e616996f3218b67bf6c75a9491bde29b7e1e9dadfdb
1>
1>#6 CACHED
1>#10 [internal] load build context
1>#10 sha256:7be3129836f3c12ea165385ef4ebac6a73479bc2e9d1eb88ee07a358fac892ea
1>#5 sha256:da9fbe6b71300cc6ddc25f980814657c4991af60b363cab5a65141bc9d00a01d
1>
1>#8 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster@sha256:4f880368ed63767483b6f6c5bf7efde3af3faba816e71ff42db50326b0386bed done
1>#7 CACHED
1>#8 sha256:83d3c0fa203acbade733bff627daa75b84c97f9d0553bcdf967a3f1d37471277 10.00MB / 10.00MB done
1>#8 sha256:97c47e73861395d28a9151f30bf24156c9c6f15d5257c57ac100840e3d6d04b7 13.70MB / 13.70MB done
1>#8 sha256:5732483fb81f596b2b19d81174388dfe410fa632e92901645b0e4d6071b8588a 13.23MB / 13.23MB done
1>#10 DONE 0.0s
1>#8 [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster@sha256:4f880368ed63767483b6f6c5bf7efde3af3faba816e71ff42db50326b0386bed
1>#8 sha256:4f880368ed63767483b6f6c5bf7efde3af3faba816e71ff42db50326b0386bed 1.80kB / 1.80kB done
1>#8 sha256:0bc3020d05f1e08b41f1c5d54650a157b1690cde7fedb1fafbc9cda70ee2ec5c 50.44MB / 50.44MB done
1>#8 sha256:a8fd09c11b021b756b7a92a4f70a3d444ce7e63a1c24e5749d236dc2c6e68514 51.84MB / 51.84MB done
1>
1>#8 sha256:8093d90df175af60d30320593d7aac24dc6f32a6ace53882adf14d2e8a6ac4bb
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 0B / 124.07MB 0.1s
1>#10 transferring context: 3.86kB 0.0s done
1>#8 sha256:b6049f4950dc536f4deb54c65f7c53f7c61c0c36a683b4563aff433a5d1e0227 6.32kB / 6.32kB done
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 1.05MB / 124.07MB 5.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 1.05MB / 124.07MB 10.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 1.05MB / 124.07MB 15.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 2.10MB / 124.07MB 20.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 2.10MB / 124.07MB 25.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 2.10MB / 124.07MB 30.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 3.15MB / 124.07MB 35.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 3.15MB / 124.07MB 40.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 3.15MB / 124.07MB 45.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 4.19MB / 124.07MB 50.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 4.19MB / 124.07MB 56.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 5.24MB / 124.07MB 61.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 5.24MB / 124.07MB 66.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 6.29MB / 124.07MB 71.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 6.29MB / 124.07MB 76.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 6.29MB / 124.07MB 81.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 7.34MB / 124.07MB 86.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 7.34MB / 124.07MB 92.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 7.34MB / 124.07MB 97.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 8.39MB / 124.07MB 102.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 8.39MB / 124.07MB 107.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 8.39MB / 124.07MB 112.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 9.44MB / 124.07MB 117.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 10.49MB / 124.07MB 122.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 10.49MB / 124.07MB 127.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 10.49MB / 124.07MB 132.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 11.53MB / 124.07MB 137.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 11.53MB / 124.07MB 143.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 11.53MB / 124.07MB 148.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 12.58MB / 124.07MB 153.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 12.58MB / 124.07MB 158.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 12.58MB / 124.07MB 163.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 13.63MB / 124.07MB 168.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 13.63MB / 124.07MB 173.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 13.63MB / 124.07MB 178.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 14.68MB / 124.07MB 183.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 14.68MB / 124.07MB 188.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 14.68MB / 124.07MB 194.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 15.73MB / 124.07MB 199.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 15.73MB / 124.07MB 204.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 15.73MB / 124.07MB 209.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 16.78MB / 124.07MB 214.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 16.78MB / 124.07MB 219.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 17.83MB / 124.07MB 224.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 17.83MB / 124.07MB 229.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 17.83MB / 124.07MB 234.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 18.87MB / 124.07MB 239.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 18.87MB / 124.07MB 244.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 18.87MB / 124.07MB 249.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 18.87MB / 124.07MB 254.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 19.92MB / 124.07MB 260.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 19.92MB / 124.07MB 265.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 20.97MB / 124.07MB 270.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 20.97MB / 124.07MB 275.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 22.02MB / 124.07MB 280.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 23.07MB / 124.07MB 285.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 23.07MB / 124.07MB 290.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 24.12MB / 124.07MB 295.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 24.12MB / 124.07MB 300.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 25.17MB / 124.07MB 305.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 25.17MB / 124.07MB 310.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 26.21MB / 124.07MB 316.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 26.21MB / 124.07MB 321.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 26.21MB / 124.07MB 326.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 27.26MB / 124.07MB 331.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 27.26MB / 124.07MB 336.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 27.26MB / 124.07MB 341.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 27.26MB / 124.07MB 346.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 28.31MB / 124.07MB 351.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 28.31MB / 124.07MB 356.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 28.31MB / 124.07MB 361.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 29.36MB / 124.07MB 366.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 29.36MB / 124.07MB 372.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 29.36MB / 124.07MB 377.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 30.41MB / 124.07MB 382.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 30.41MB / 124.07MB 387.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 31.46MB / 124.07MB 392.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 31.46MB / 124.07MB 397.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 31.46MB / 124.07MB 402.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 31.46MB / 124.07MB 407.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 32.51MB / 124.07MB 412.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 32.51MB / 124.07MB 417.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 32.51MB / 124.07MB 422.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 33.55MB / 124.07MB 427.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 33.55MB / 124.07MB 432.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 33.55MB / 124.07MB 437.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 34.60MB / 124.07MB 442.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 34.60MB / 124.07MB 448.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 35.65MB / 124.07MB 453.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 35.65MB / 124.07MB 458.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 35.65MB / 124.07MB 463.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 36.70MB / 124.07MB 468.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 36.70MB / 124.07MB 473.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 36.70MB / 124.07MB 478.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 37.75MB / 124.07MB 483.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 37.75MB / 124.07MB 488.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 37.75MB / 124.07MB 493.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 38.80MB / 124.07MB 498.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 38.80MB / 124.07MB 503.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 38.80MB / 124.07MB 509.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 39.85MB / 124.07MB 514.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 39.85MB / 124.07MB 519.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 39.85MB / 124.07MB 524.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 40.89MB / 124.07MB 529.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 40.89MB / 124.07MB 534.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 40.89MB / 124.07MB 539.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 41.94MB / 124.07MB 544.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 41.94MB / 124.07MB 549.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 41.94MB / 124.07MB 554.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 42.99MB / 124.07MB 559.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 44.04MB / 124.07MB 564.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 44.04MB / 124.07MB 569.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 45.09MB / 124.07MB 574.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 45.09MB / 124.07MB 580.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 45.09MB / 124.07MB 585.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 46.14MB / 124.07MB 590.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 46.14MB / 124.07MB 595.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 47.19MB / 124.07MB 600.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 47.19MB / 124.07MB 605.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 47.19MB / 124.07MB 610.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 48.23MB / 124.07MB 615.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 48.23MB / 124.07MB 620.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 48.23MB / 124.07MB 625.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 49.28MB / 124.07MB 630.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 49.28MB / 124.07MB 636.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 50.33MB / 124.07MB 641.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 50.33MB / 124.07MB 646.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 51.38MB / 124.07MB 651.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 51.38MB / 124.07MB 656.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 51.38MB / 124.07MB 661.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 52.43MB / 124.07MB 666.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 52.43MB / 124.07MB 671.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 52.43MB / 124.07MB 676.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 53.48MB / 124.07MB 681.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 53.48MB / 124.07MB 686.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 54.53MB / 124.07MB 691.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 54.53MB / 124.07MB 696.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 55.57MB / 124.07MB 701.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 55.57MB / 124.07MB 707.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 56.62MB / 124.07MB 712.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 56.62MB / 124.07MB 717.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 56.62MB / 124.07MB 722.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 57.67MB / 124.07MB 727.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 57.67MB / 124.07MB 732.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 57.67MB / 124.07MB 737.7s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 58.72MB / 124.07MB 742.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 58.72MB / 124.07MB 747.8s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 59.77MB / 124.07MB 752.9s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 59.77MB / 124.07MB 758.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 59.77MB / 124.07MB 763.0s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 60.82MB / 124.07MB 768.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 60.82MB / 124.07MB 773.1s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 60.82MB / 124.07MB 778.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 61.87MB / 124.07MB 783.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 61.87MB / 124.07MB 788.2s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 62.91MB / 124.07MB 793.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 62.91MB / 124.07MB 798.3s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 62.91MB / 124.07MB 803.4s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 62.91MB / 124.07MB 808.5s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 63.96MB / 124.07MB 813.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 63.96MB / 124.07MB 818.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 63.96MB / 124.07MB 823.6s
1>#8 sha256:fc3e2673a83ad8e020638e22eb5d1245fd90af2001cbfbba022ae65d450f2a6f 65.01MB / 124.07MB 828.8s
```

Sometimes when it reaches 124.07MB, it again goes into cycle. Not sure why

Comment: Have you tried with the `docker build --no-cache` flag?

Comment: @Henkolicious where to edit this setting? I restarted docker and tried again. It worked. First docker build took too long time. Rest of the builds were faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarted docker and tried build again and it worked.

Comment: Sometimes we think too much. All we need is to restart..